# ExtJS using MVVM

Tags: extjs

New to extjs, and I need to rewrite the code from MVM to MVVM . Part of the code below,

```
Ext.define('ExtMVC.model.Department', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory'
        ,reader: 'json'
        ,data: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Foo'}
            ,{id: 2, name: 'Bar'}
            ,{id: 30, name: 'Baz'}
        ]
    }
});
```

get full code and example and jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/vdazU/

Comment: With your example you still declare the models the same way you are doing now, the only difference (if you want) is that you could set your store inside the viewModel (if it's not being shared by any other view).

Comment: Thank you I think I can try that out.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, it just looks like you need to add a view model definition and then bind your view to the model. 
Take a look a the fiddle below. I grabbed your posted fiddle and made some adjustments with inline comments that should help you out.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23eb

Here is a quick reference:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html